# Syntax error (missing operator) from Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following query:

```
SELECT a.Itemid, b.[Date], b.[Hour], c.Name1
FROM (([Report] a 
inner join [Results] b 
on a.itemid = b.[Id]) 
inner join [Characteristics] c on a.itemid = c.[Id]) 
where b.Gener > 0 and a.Id in (534560,534993,550300,1000033) and c.ype != 'DD' and c.tType != 'DL'
```

I am not sure how to modify the above code to make it work. I am using pyodbc connection to run the above query.

The error is:

```
('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
```

Comment: There's no `!=` in SQL. The not equals operator is `<>`

Comment: Be sure to heed: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

Comment: Whoever marked this question to be closed should probably explain himself, so far this looks OK to me

Comment: Is pyodbc connection useful for Access? It looks like its for SQL Server? Also, if youre just using access as a way to easily run queries to SQL Server via this connection, I think you might want to change how youre opening queries

Comment: @ErikA SQL Server can use bang equals as a not operator, AccessSQL cannot. I felt thats was worth mentioning. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-equal-to-transact-sql-exclamation?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Same goes for Oracle http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_not_equal_operator.htm

And mysql https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-equal-operator.php

Comment: @DougCoats There's none in ANSI SQL though, and as you said none in Access. It's best to stick to ANSI SQL features when sufficient to avoid errors like these.

Comment: @ErikA While that's a fair argument, its important to be more clear about that kind of thing as not all devs are aware of what ANSI standard is or if its even relevant at all (this is not an argument id like to get into) - portable code is important though. Saying it isnt in SQL is not true where as saying its not ANSI Standard is true.